# String in double quotes don't change the color in Android Studio - Just curious

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am working on Android studio 2.2.1 and I have also experienced this in older versions of it.
I dont know what is the reason behind this.
The color of characters between the double quotes is changed to green, but in some cases it dont changes.
[image]
Why is it so?

If you think special characters are the issue, see this.
[image]

Comment: when a special charector like `/` added in string it will not changed to green

Comment: @AbhishekSingh see the edited question

Comment: its problem of split method... string in split method not turn green.... however its not a big deal.. its just IDE problem

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio knows the strings are regexes and applies RegExp syntax and error highlighting on the strings in this case. You can control this highlighting inside strings in the preferences under `File | Settings | Editor | Language Injections`.